# CakePHP 2.x, ACL - Add/Edit rights of one group to another

Tags: acl, cakephp-2.1

I am working with CakePHP 2.1.3 ACL component. I have created four groups Administrators, Managers, Editors and Registered Users. For user management module I want provide access as listed below:

Administrators -> All 

Managers -> Add,Edit,Delete Editors and Registered Users

Editors -> Add,Edit,Delete Registered users 

Registered Users -> None.

Can I accomplish this with ACL and Auth Component? If not, then suggest some other way.

Comment: I would suggest to use the cake ACL component. See their tutorial, it is easy to follow!

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is possible with ACL. There is even much more possible with ACL.

[CakePHP documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html)

There is also a nice tutorial about ACL written by [John Wiseman](http://bloggingsquared.com/web-development/cakephp-acl-tutorial/), maybe you should read this first.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but Acl is overkill to handle such permissions, just use Auth's ControllerAuthorize adapter and put in your UsersController an `isAuthorized()` method along these lines:

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    $userGroup = $user['User']['group'];
    if ($userGroup == 'admin' || in_array($this->action, array('index', 'view'))) {
        return true;
    }
    if ($userGroup == 'registered') {
        return false;
    }
    if ($this->action == 'add') {
        return true;
    }
    if (in_array($this->action, array('edit', 'delete'))) {
        $id = $this->request->params['pass'][0];
        $group = $this->User->field('group', array('User.id' => $id));
        if ($group == 'registered') {
            return true;
        }
        if ($group == 'editor' && $userGroup == 'moderator') {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

add action is not handled here, and is always allowed, you should just show less options to set a group, when adding a new user, based off logged in user.
You did not mention how to handle index and view, i suppose all users are allowed to do that.

Comment: this is a bad way to do, because it gets really messy if you change actions, add actions, add other controllers and stuff. The ACL is really the way to do! Also ACL takes crud in consideration. Also, cakephp has builtIn ACL component.

Comment: Hugo, i am very much aware of what is built into CakePHP and i can assure you that using isAuthorized() is a much better way then Acl, especially Db backed Acl, which is the most (ab)used type. Also one could build their own Authorize adapter to handle permissions.